# Camel Producer template in a custom AsyncProcessor

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have created a custom endpoint to leveraging asynchronous processing of some data. Now I want to communicate the result of the processing to another route so the result can be saved in a database but I don't know how I can get access to a producer template within my AsyncProcessor.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this FAQ about using a producer template:
http://camel.apache.org/why-does-camel-use-too-many-threads-with-producertemplate.html

The intend is to IoC the producer template / or lookup the template when you need it. You can also get hold of the CamelContext API from the Exchange and then create a new producer template to use (only once) and keep reusing the template. If you do not want to reuse the template, then make sure to stop it after usage.

Comment: I used the example in your book to do my fast Async component...;) Can you give an example of how to do this with the ERPProducer example from your book?